# How can I implement conditional rendering using map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made 5 blocks and want to make the letters on each block thick when the mouse is hover. I made `isHover` state and changed the thickness of the writing according to the state, but the problem is that the thickness of all five changes. I think I can solve it by using conditional rendering, but I don't know how to use it. Of course, it can be implemented only with css, but I want to implement it with conditional rendering because I am practicing the code concisely.

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const array = [
    { id: "1", title: "ABC" },
    { id: "2", title: "DEF" },
    { id: "3", title: "GHI" },
    { id: "4", title: "JKL" },
    { id: "5", title: "MNO" }
  ];

  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Head isHover={isHover}>
      <div className="header">
        {array.map((content, id) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="header__title"
              onMouseEnter={() => {
                setIsHover(true);
              }}
              onMouseLeave={() => {
                setIsHover(false);
              }}
            >
              {content.title}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Head>
  );
}

const Head = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  .header {
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header__title {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: ${(props) => (props.isHover ? "700" : "400")};
  }
`;
```

**codesandbox**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-cherry-53pr2r?file=/src/App.js:0-1170

Comment: You're over thinking it. Just set the font inside the handler callback.

Comment: Why use JS/React for this at all? Just use CSS

Comment: Using `:hover` is the best way to do this, but if you do need to know how to do it in React/Styled: change the div with `.header__title` to a separate SC, remove the `hover` prop from the parent component, and only pass it to that one. (Also don't forget to pass a unique key to each element returned by your map — probably `content.title`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same state for all the 5 blocks. There are multiple approaches you could take to solve this problem.

**1. Multiple states**

You could create 5 different `isHover<N>` states (maybe a single one, but as an array)

**2. Component extraction**

You could just extract out a component for each entry in array and do state management in that component.

```
function App() {
  const array = [...];

  return (
    <Head>
      <div className="header">
        {array.map((content, id) => (
          <HeaderTitle key={content.id} content={content} />
        )}
      </div>
    </Head>
  );
}

function HeaderTitle({ content }) {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <StyledHeaderTitle
      isHover={isHover}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
    >
      {content.title}
    </StyledHeaderTitle>
  );
}

const StyledHeaderTitle = styled.div`
  font-weight: ${(props) => (props.isHover ? "700" : "400")};
`
```

**3. Using `style` prop**

Directly apply the font weight using the `style` prop (An extension to approach 2)

```
function HeaderTitle({ content }) {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <StyledHeaderTitle
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
      style={{ fontWeight: isHover ? "700" : "400" }}
    >
      {content.title}
    </StyledHeaderTitle>
  );
}
```

**4. CSS**

CSS already allows you to track hover states over different elements and you don't need to manually track it in javascript.

```scss
.header__title {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 400;

  &:hover {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all the way you wrote it down was helpful!!

Comment: Which one would you personally use @vighnesh153?

Comment: I would use the 4th one (CSS or styled-components). Reason being we don't need to use javascript for stuff that can be done without it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use React state and event listeners here, you can do it all in CSS instead:

```
.header__title {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header__title:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add  this pseudo class and you're good to go

```
.header__title:hover {
font-weight: 700;
}
```